# not able to run "group by" query in dbvisualizer 6.5

Tags: sql, group-by, dbvisualizer

I am executing the following sql in dbvisualizer

```
Select column1,column2,column3 from table group by column3;
```

It is showing the following error:

```
15:47:09  [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 979, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]
```

but it is giving result when i am querieng like:

```
Select column1 from table group by column1;
```

Is there any syntax error in query or some configuration or support problem.

Answer (score 0):

In a [`group by` statement](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-group-by-sql-tutorial/) you should specify the same columns of the ones in the `select` (except for the sum, count, etc)

So your query

```
Select column1,column2,column3 from table group by column3;
```

should be

```
Select column1,column2,column3 from table group by column1,column2,column3;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CLAUSE AND GROUP BY CLAUSE columns are like HUSBAND AND WIFE.The aggregate operations you perform in the SELECT are their children. I mean to say that there should be equal number of columns in your SELECT and GROUP BY CLAUSE.It's a **thumb rule**.